# [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Size(150528) must match the product of shape 1]

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am using a custom model I built using transfer learning with MobileNetV2 then converted to TF.js format.

Model takes in input of (batch_size, 224,224,3)
I am not sure where the size(150528) is from cause it is not present in my model.summary()

[Link to model summary as it is too long to post here](https://github.com/yudhiesh1997/Driver-Drowsiness-Detection/blob/master/DriverDrowsiness%20(1).ipynb)

Code for the model in Python:

```
baseModel = MobileNetV2(include_top=False,
         input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE,
         weights='imagenet')

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(512, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)
# place the head FC model on top of the base model
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Code for making the predictions in Javascript for React Native

```
// get predictions from the model 

  const getPrediction = async tensor => {
    tensor = tensor.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3);


    if (!tensor) {
      console.log("Prediction not found");
      return;
    }
    const prediction = await loadedModel.predict(tensor, 32);
    console.log(`Predictions: ${JSON.stringify(prediction)}`);

    if (!prediction || prediction.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Only take the predictions with a probability of 30% and greater
    if (prediction[0].probability > 0.3) {
      //Stop looping
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrameId);
      setPredictionFound(true);
      setModelPrediction(prediction[0].className);
      tensor.dispose();
    }
  };

  // Load the model from the models folder
  const loadModel = async () => {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
      bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights)
    );
    console.log("Model loaded!");
    return model;
  };


  // Handling the camera input and converting it into tensors to be used in the
  // model for predictions
  const handleCameraStream = imageAsTensors => {
    const loop = async () => {
      //loadedModel is the custom model I created and stored in state
      if (loadedModel !== null) {
        if (frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrames === 0) {
          const imageTensor = imageAsTensors.next().value;
          const faces = await getPrediction(imageTensor);
        }
      }

      frameCount += 1;
     //requestAnimationFrameID = 0
     // makePredictionsEveryNFrames = 3
      frameCount = frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrames;
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    // loop infinitely to constantly make predictions
    loop();
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue regarding the input shape I was passing to make predictions and was solved with the following code:

```
const model = await loadedModel;
const prediction = model.predict(tensor.reshape([1, 224, 224, 3]));
```